# Vue3 app instance being created but not mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I'm integrating Vue3 to handle reactivity of a specific page of a webapp, so it's not a spa.

Vue instance is being created, but not mounted, nor the `created()` method is being called upon creation.

I'm using webpack and laravel-mix to compile the script, but i'm not sure if this is involved.

Here are the script and the page console output: as you can see there is no error in the console, the instance itself is being logged, but it seems that `mounted()` neither `created()` methods are being called, thus the first 2 warnings.

##### The script

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'

const app = createApp({
    data: {
        width: 90,
        height: 210,
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted');
    },
    created() {
        console.log('created');
    }
});

app.mount('#app');

console.log(app);

console.log('test');
```

###### Page console output

[image]

Comment: Of course it's mounted, this can be seen in `_container`. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. `width`, etc aren't in use in your code. FWIW `data` object is deprecated, a function needs to be used instead

Comment: Yes, data should be a function which returns an object. 
`data() { return { width: 90, height: 210} }`.

Comment: @fudo The compiler is warning you that your component is trying to render undeclared props. Even though you declare `width`/`height` in the root component (in `createApp`), that doesn't make them avaiable to all child components. You'll need to move those props into the child component that actually uses them.

Comment: @tony19 I don't have any child component at the moment, i've just started integrating vue so this is less than a walking skeleton of the project.

Comment: @fudo Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @EstusFlask ok, but as you can see i got no errors nor warnings on using an object instead of a function for the `data`, and moreover it's like that the `mounted()` nor the `created()` methods are called upon the respective lifecycles hooks as none of the logs are logged

Comment: There was a warning regarding `data` in Vue 2, in Vue 3 it's considered a mistake. Just pasted your code into empty project, and it results in `dataOptions.call is not a function` error for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It was so simple

As I mentioned in the question,

> I'm using webpack and laravel-mix to compile the script, but i'm not sure if this is involved.

In fact, a wrong `webpack.mix.js` configuration was the problem, since I forgot to call `.vue()` after the `.js()` command as in the example of the [vue section of the Laravel Mix docs](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue).